# GTK MenuItem with counter bubble on right

Tags: python, ubuntu, gtk, gnome

I want to ask if there's a simple way to do MenuItem like this http://dl.dropbox.com/u/865508/menuitem.png in PyGtk (or maybe some other language rather than python). I think it would be helpful for a lot of people)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes; a `MenuItem` is also a `Container`, so you can add any widgets you like to it. Just create an empty one with `gtk.MenuItem(label=None)` and add an `HBox` with a label on the left and an icon (for the counter bubble) on the right.